# Django 3.0: How to use different Boostrap versions in same template

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I have made a ***template (Base.html)*** in my django project, of Bootstrap 4 which working is fine independently.

I have also made another ***template (Child_Base.html)*** which is made with Bootstrap 3 and supposed to be injected in Base.html.

But what happening here is, when I include BS3 template in first one it is ruining many things. So, I am looking for a solution in which both co-exist and doesn't spoil other one.

---

Code of **Base.html** is supposed as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        {% block bodyblock %}
            Hello World!
            {% include "Child_Base.html" %}
        {% endblock %}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of **Child_Base.html** is supposed as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        {% block bodyblock %}
            Good Morning!
        {% endblock %}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

In actual scenario, there is product page, displaying all the books available for user to add in cart (made in BS4) in which I want to include search box (made in BS3). But code is tangled and not so self-elaborated so I have used above examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why you want this?

you either include CSS files in your templatename.html file or in a different name.css file that is linked to your template, when you include bt3 and bt4 browser DOM looks like this:

> pages:
>
> index.html
>
> files:
>
> bt3.min.css
>
> bt4.min.css

and then it gets crazy cause two different CSS files with same tags are in browser DOM.

I'm not telling this is not possible cause in frontend frameworks like vue.js you can config it to use CSS locally just for one component, but Django doesn't generate files like that so you can't have two different CSS files isolated from each other for one HTML page.

on second Thought:

maybe if you make your page.html with a scheme like this:

```
headers and other head tags...
<body>
    <section>
        <style>
            include the entire bootstrap 4 css here
        </style>
        enter your bt4 elements here
    </section>
    <section>
        <style>
            include entire bootstrap 3 css here
        </style>
        enter your bt3 elements here
    </section>
</body>
```

you should put .min.css in  this may cause the browser to render the page with your desired styles as always CSS files are overwritten by lower CSS's in the file.

Comment: This is a total different approach you are talking about. There must be some other solution more related like maybe some django block tag or something other than that which won't let child template override.

Comment: oh, ok good luck with that, and be sure to share...

Answer (score 0):

I use the below method, hope it helps

in base.html, use a block

```
<html>
    <head>
    {% block main_css %}
    # bootstrap v3
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    {% endblock %}
...
```

in other child_template.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main_css %}
# other style
<link href="{% static 'css/style_2023.css' %}?time={% now "U" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
# bootstrap 4
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mdb_4/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

It will then replace the main_css block in base.html.